# How do I check if an element is present with Selenium (Python)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I'm trying to select the name "Saleem" from the HTML. It is inside a table, but I don't know how if that is relevant. The name might not always be there, so I'm trying to find a way to select the element if the name is included in the table. For example "Liam" does not appear when searched, but "saleem" does. How do I click the link that appears when saleem is searched? For some reason, Selenium can't find the element with the code I wrote below.

Here is the website (I just put Saleem in the name category and searched):
https://sanctionssearch.ofac.treas.gov/default.aspx

I tried the code below, but unfortunately does not work.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("btnDetails").click()

 <a> id="btnDetails" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$gvSearchResults$ctl02$btnDetails&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;Details.aspx?id=5839&quot;, false, true))" style="color:Blue">AL-IFRI, Saleem </a>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will select the search results from the name `saleem` and take you to Saleem's page. You can do what you want to do on that page then. To come back to the search results just use `browser.back()`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser_options = Options()
browser_options.add_argument('--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 4.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36"')
browser_options.add_argument('start-maximized')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/bin/chromedriver.exe',options=browser_options)
browser.get('https://sanctionssearch.ofac.treas.gov/default.aspx')
search_box = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_txtLastName"]')))
search_box.send_keys('Saleem')
search_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(4)
try:
    results = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gvSearchResults"]/tbody').find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    for result in results:
        button = result.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
        button.click()
        #Do Something
        browser.back(()
        browser.refresh()
```

Comment: If the answer helped please accept it by clicking the grey tick under the vote sign. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use it inside `try..except`

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

# YOUR CODE 
        
try:
  webdriver.find_element_by_id('btnDetails')
except NoSuchElementException:
  # Element does not exist
else:
  # Element exists
```

Comment: Hi, but how do I select the element? I've tried select by id, but it can't find the element?

Comment: it still works in 2022